# Firestore security rules and vuefire

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

i have the following sample app here: [Github repo](https://github.com/maltewirz/firebase-vue-walkie-talkie)

It uses [vuefire](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/) in ChatList.vue

```
// vuefire firestore component manages the real-time stream to that reactive data property.
firestore() {
    return {
        chats: db.collection('chats').where('members', 'array-contains', this.uid)
    }
},
```

I now wrote security rules to secure the data, but can't seem to get the combination of vuefire and security rules to work:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
    // THIS IS THE PART I'D LIKE TO REMOVE
    match /chats/{chatId=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;  
    }
    // THIS WORKS AS INTENDED, AND I'D LIKE TO INCLUDE "READ"
    match /chats/{chatId}/{documents=**} {
      allow write: if chatRoomPermission(chatId)
    }
    function chatRoomPermission(chatId) {
      return request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/chats/$(chatId)).data.members;
    }
  }
}
```

So the goal is: make the individual chats only readable and writable to users that are in the members array in firestore. (Currently i achieved this partially, since all chats are readable to anyone, but only writable to users in the members array.)

Do i have to rewrite the vuefire component so i can have the following security rule? (It gives an error message: listing of chats not possible due to missing permissions)

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
    match /chats/{chatId}/{documents=**} {
      allow read, write: if chatRoomPermission(chatId)
    }
    function chatRoomPermission(chatId) {
      return request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/chats/$(chatId)).data.members;
    }
  }
}
```

**For completeness, the working solution is (credits to Renaud Tarnec):**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
    match /chats/{chatId=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.members; 
    }
    match /chats/{chatId}/{documents=**} {
      allow read, write: if chatRoomPermission(chatId)
    }
    function chatRoomPermission(chatId) {
      return request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/chats/$(chatId)).data.members;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to check, in your Security Rules, if a given value (the user `uid` in this case) is contained in a field of type Array in your document, you can use the `in` operator of the [`List`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List) type.

So, the following should do the trick:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
    // THIS IS THE PART I'D LIKE TO REMOVE
    match /chats/{chatId=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.members;
    }

    // ....
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you like to say a little bit more about **why** this works for the stated case?

Comment: @DougStevenson Good suggestion indeed Doug, answer updated :-)

Comment: One final question: Why does ``` match /chats/{chatId=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.members; 
    }``` work but for ```    match /chats/{chatId}/{documents=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/chats/$(chatId)).data.members;
    }``i have to make a firestore call? Is it because the former has the members data in the requested document itself, whereas the latter has the members data only in its parent document?